# Рекурсивный вызов main

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Что будет при рекурсивном вызове функции main???

```
int main() {
  main();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532912/call-main-itself-in-c

Comment: Это некорректная (ill-formed) программа, т.е. ошибка компиляции.

Comment: @AnT нет ошибок компиляции

Comment: @trademark: Это глюк вашего компилятора. Что за компилятор?

Comment: @AnT визуальная студия 2017

Comment: @trademark: Требуемое стандартом языка диагностическое сообщение от компилятора вы получили? Это - ошибка компиляции.

Comment: @AnT разве? да получил но я думал ошибка компиляции это когда не компилируется

Comment: @trademark: Термин "компилируется" в мире С++ означает "проходит компиляцию без выдачи требуемых стандартом языка диагностических сообщений". Если вы получили требуемое стандартом диагностическое сообщение - это называется *НЕ компилируется*. Если вы не получили на этот код требуемого стандартом диагностического сообщения, то это баг компилятора. С точки зрения языка С++ код ошибочен. Все остальное - особенности/глюки/баги вашего компилятора

Comment: @AnT откуда вы знаете? нам препод по другому говорит - не компилируется значит не запускается а тут запускается значит компилируется

Comment: @trademark: Ваш "препод" несет чушь. Компиляторы языков С и С++ работают по принципу "мусор на входе - мусор на выходе". Если какой-то мусор на входе у вас "компилируется и запускается"- то поздравляю, флаг вам в руки, но к языку С++ это никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @AnT Дубков - гад!

Comment: @trademark: Дубков? Уж не БГУ ли?

Comment: @AnT Минск, БГУ, ФПМИ :)

Comment: Так и подумал. У меня на ФПМИ практику вел в девяностых :)

Comment: @AnT и сейчас ведёт :)

Comment: @AnT приезжайте прочитайте лекцию по C++, я бы послушал :-)

Comment: @trademark: Я в этом году был на дне факультета. Забрался на шестой
 этаж и там на доске дописал от себя "7*8=54"(https://imgur.com/a/nMnXaSv). Кто ж меня после этого пустит лекции читать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандарт запрещает использовать функцию `main`

> **6.6.1 main function**
>   3. The function main shall not be used within a program. ...

Однако, некоторые компиляторы могут отклоняться от стандартного поведения.

К примеру, возьмем `clang 3.8.0`.
С флагом `-pedantic-errors` компилятор выдает ошибку:

> error: ISO C++ does not allow 'main' to be used by a program

https://rextester.com/QBKCG46413

Однако, если убрать данную опцию, то поведение, возможно, будет неожиданным.
Возьмем небольшой код:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Some
{
    Some() { std::cout << "begin" << std::endl; }
    ~Some() { std::cout << "end" << std::endl; }
};

Some s;

int main()
{
    main();
}
```

Объект `s` предназначен просто для вывода сообщений до запуска `main` и после её выполнения.

Если собрать это с флагом `-O0`, то получаем честный `SIGSEGV`: https://rextester.com/XTRATW71243

Однако, уже с флагом `-O1` мы видим вывод обоих сообщений и никаких ошибок

> begin
>   end

т.е. `main` выполнился успешно: https://rextester.com/XUF23687

Это связано с оптимизациями при неопределенном поведении.
Дело в том, что бесконечная рекурсия без изменения состояния - неопределенное поведение, поэтому компилятор вправе сделать что угодно. В данном случае `clang` видит, что рекурсия не меняет внешнее состояние, и имеется всего одна точка выхода - `return 0` в конце `main` (будет добавлен компилятором автоматически, т.к. в `main` отсутствует явный `return`), поэтому всю эту рекурсию можно законно удалить:

> **4.6 Program execution**
>   1. The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.<sup>6</sup>
>   ...
>   6) This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this International Standard as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program. **For instance, an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced.**

Если посмотреть код функции main после компиляции, то он таков:

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/63h1rn

Answer (score 3):

Стандартом языка запрещается любое использование функции `main`:

> **6.6.1 main function [basic.start.main]**
>   3 The function *main* shall not be used within a program.

Answer (score 2):

Переполнение стека, поскольку нет никакого условия завершения рекурсии...

Кстати, VC++ 2017, например, честно об этом предупреждает.
А вот GCC на ideone компилирует без предупреждений.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `main` обладает следующими специальными свойствами:

1. Она нигде не может быть использована в программе,

   - в частности её нельзя вызывать рекурсивно;
   - нельзя взять её адрес.
2. Её нельзя объявлять и нельзя перегружать: фактически имя `main` зарезервировано в глобальном пространстве имён для функций (хотя это имя может быть использовано для именования классов, пространства имён, перечислений и любых сущностей не в глобальных пространствах имён, за исключением того, что функция с именем `'main'` не может быть объявлена со связыванием для языка C в любом пространстве имён (начиная с C++17)).
3. Её нельзя объявить как удалённую или определить со связыванием для C (начиная с C++17), `inline`, `static` или `constexpr`.
4. В теле функции `main` не обязателен оператор `return`: при завершении функции `main` без оператора `return` эффект будет тот же самый, как при выполнении `return 0;`.
5. Выполнение `return` (или неявного `return` при достижении конца функции `main`) эквивалентно нормальному выходу из функции (которое уничтожает объекты с автоматическим временем жизни) с последующим вызовом `std::exit` с тем же самым аргументом, который был передан в `return`. (`std::exit` уничтожает статические объекты и завершает программу).
6. Если функция `main` определена как `function-try-block`, исключения, брошенные деструкторами статических объектов (которые уничтожаются при вызове `std::exit`), не отлавливаются функцией.
7. (начиная с C++14) Тип возвращаемого значения функцией `main` не может быть выведен (`auto main() {...}` не разрешён).

https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: Поправьте форматирование. А можно было и ссылки на оригинал добавить:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function и на английскую версию: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function